# BQ2057WSN Charging issues

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging

I have designed a battery charging Module using BQ2057WSN IC to charge a 7.4V,6600mAH Li-ion battery. According to my calculation the charging current is set at 625mA.

The input power source to the Charging module (DC+) is 12VDC, 2A SMPS and the circuit is drawing 625mA from the Power source (SMPS). Now, I have connect a multi meter in series with the battery pack as shown in picture to see how much current the battery is drawing. I have found the multi meter reading as 250mA. The measure battery voltage is 7V, which means the battery is not fully charged.

So, my question is, if the charging circuit is drawing 625mA from the power source, why only 250mA current is drawing by the battery while charging? The battery should also draw the same amount of current (625mA), isn't it?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Put your multimeter in series with the 12 volt feed and see what it measures there. Then, with your multimeter measuring voltage, measure the volt drop across Rsns.

Comment: @Andyaka, I have measured the input feed current as 625mA and the voltage drop across Rsns is 120mV. Both are as expected, Right?

Comment: I think you might have a problem with the impedance of your meter when measuring current. I suspect that it introduces several ohms of impedance when placed in series with your battery and prevents the full 625 mA flowing. Try using a spare 0.2 ohm resistor in series with the battery and infer the current from the volt drop.

Comment: @Andyaka, "Try using a spare 0.2 ohm resistor in series with the battery and infer the current from the volt drop"; I have done as per your advice and found the voltage drop across spare 0.2 ohm resistor as 110mV which means 550mA current is going to the battery. It is ok. But previously multi meter showing wrong measurement in the battery end due to the insertions of impedance. But how the same multi meter is showing correct value in the DC feeding end? Why it is not inserting impedance in the DC feeding end?

Comment: because contacts are contacts and not perfect conductors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:**

Extra voltage drop in the battery circuit has significant effect on charging as it makes the battery voltage appear higher than it is.  Extra voltage drop in the input circuit is allowed for by reducing the voltage drop in Q1 by an equal amount.

**Detail:**

If the meter has significant resistance on its current range, when the meter is in series with the battery the voltage drop across the meter makes the battery voltage appear higher than it is. If the battery is close to full voltage then the IR drop across the meter can make the battery appear to be fully charged. The charger reduces the current accordingly, the IR drop lessens and Ichg again increases. A balance point will be reached where Vbattery + IR "fool" the charger into maintaining a lower than correct current.

When Vin is 12V and Vbattery is <= 7.4 V the charger drops the surplus voltage  - mainly across Q1.   If the meter is connected in series and drops some voltage then the voltage across Q1 is adjusted by the control circuitry - so the meter resistance will have minimal effect.

Answer (score 1):

> "Try using a spare 0.2 ohm resistor in series with the battery and
>   infer the current from the volt drop"; I have done as per your advice
>   and found the voltage drop across spare 0.2 ohm resistor as 110mV
>   which means 550mA current is going to the battery. It is ok. But
>   previously multi meter showing wrong measurement in the battery end
>   due to the insertions of impedance. But how the same multi meter is
>   showing correct value in the DC feeding end? Why it is not inserting
>   impedance in the DC feeding end?

The node on the battery side will be quite sensitive to volt drops in the feed-line and your meter's impedance probably upset things too much and the regulator chip thought the battery voltage was higher than it was. This is because the BAT pin on the chip would see battery voltage plus meter volt drop and erroneously make a judgement call on whether that battery was close to fully charged.

If you'd have put the meter directly in series with Q1's collector it will probably be a more fruitful story as is the case when you put the meter in series with the power supply.

Comment: Let to to check by putting multi meter directly in series with Q1's collector.

Comment: Andyaka, RussellMcMahon, Today put a multi meter in series with Q1 and measured the current at the battery end is 300mA (like yesterday/ Previous case) and  at the same time the current drawn from the power source is also 300mA( yesterday I have observed it as 600mA). I have also observed today that before inserting the multi meter, the battery terminal voltage was 7.39V  and the circuit was drawing 600mA from the power source. And before inserting the multi meter in series with Q1, the battery terminal voltage become 7.44V  and the circuit was drawing 300mA from the power source. Why so?

Comment: @ Andyaka RussellMcMahon,When I was doing the same experiment ( putting the multi meter in series with Q1) with a battery having voltage 6V, I have found that both the current drawn from the power source as well as current in the battery terminal was 600mA. But, when this was doing with a  battery having voltage 7.39V, the current reduces to 300mA with insertions of multi meter. Why the current is different in these two case as in both the cases the batteries are not fully charged.

Comment: You’ve already accepted an answer and these appear to be new questions beyond the scope of the original so I would suggest you raise a new question with unambiguous diagrams of what you connected and where you connected it.